# Wordpress - is it possible to have multiple posts page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to achieve a multiples posts pages so I can style them differently based on their content

for example:

```
articles posts page -  /essay-&-articles
books posts page - /books
foods posts page - /foods

article single post page - /essay-&-articles/1
book single post page - /books/1
food single post page - /foods/1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're looking for [permalinks and slugs](https://wordpress.com/support/permalinks-and-slugs/). You can use the `category` and `post_id` for the URL, as long as your posts already have the category(ies) assigned.

In your WordPress Dashboard, go to Settings, then Permalinks. There are some existing permalinks you can use, but based on what you want, the entry will look like this:

`/%category%/%post_id%/`

Each post has a unique ID, and can be accessed using the same ID on any category(ies) it has assigned. You can read the [WordPress documentation](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/customize-permalinks/) about permalinks for other customization ideas, too.